# Can I get stack trace as text inside strored procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, debugging

I found this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-stack-trace.html suggesting that some stack trace can be retrieved from CLI. I'm wondering if it's possible to get this information from inside stored procedure, co I can log it into some table directly

Comment: then you read something completely different than me, i think it says you can compile mysqld ,  so that it saves the stack track in the error log file "on some systems", this can be useful if your system crushes and the error log and system logs don't give any indication, why this is. I suppose you load the erro file int5o a table, but what for

Comment: *suggesting that some stack trace can be retrieved from CLI.* No! Stack trace is saved into error log, which is accessible from some tool in host OS, but not from MySQL CLI client. *I'm wondering if it's possible to get this information from inside stored procedure, co I can log it into some table directly* How? MySQL is died! of course after its restart you may try to import error log file as a common irregular text file - but I think this makes no sense.